# Is there a way to see the origin of Android and iOS app sessions in Google Analytics?

Tags: google-analytics, google-analytics-sdk, google-analytics-firebase

Is there a way to see the origins of Android and iOS app sessions in Google Analytics?

For example, did the session start because the user tapped the app icon on their device? 
Because they deep linked from the web? 
Because they tapped a push notification?